# Unicode Portability

Tags: c++, unicode

I'm currently taking care of an application that uses `std::string` and `char` for string operations - which is fine on **linux**, since Linux is agnostic to Unicode (or so it seems; I don't really know, so please correct me if I'm telling stories here). This current style naturally leads to this kind of function/class declarations:

```
std::string doSomethingFunkyWith(const std::string& thisdata)
{
    /* .... */
}
```

However, if `thisdata` contains unicode characters, it will be displayed wrongly on windows, since `std::string` can't hold unicode characters on Windows.

So I thought up this concept:

```
namespace MyApplication {
#ifdef UNICODE
    typedef std::wstring  string_type;
    typedef wchar_t       char_type;
#else
    typedef std::string   string_type;
    typedef char          char_type;
#endif

    /* ... */
    string_type doSomethingFunkyWith(const string_type& thisdata)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Is this a good concept to go with to support Unicode on windows?

My current toolchain consists of gcc/clang on Linux, and wine+MinGW for Windows support (crosstesting also happens via wine), if that matters.

Comment: I think it's reasonable. I believe this is the approach taken by many libraries, such as wxWidgets.

Comment: Yes this is done with lots of libraries, Windows for one, as you mentioned.

Comment: More exactly, most Linux programs handle Unicode as UTF-8, which is compatible with `std::string`.  But that means `size()` and `length()` will give the number of bytes, but not necessarily the number of code points or glyphs.  Depending on what you're doing with the strings, you may not need more info.

Comment: There are more problems. You can't call `utf8str.find_first_of("ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ")`. Well, the compiler allows it, but it will produce the wrong results.

Comment: @MSalters that is why there is the `_TEXT` macro, which will prefix strings with L if `UNICODE` is defined

Comment: @Marlon: `_TEXT` is a Microsoft idiom, and doesn't work on Linux. Besides, `_TEXT("ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ")` doesn't make sense. You can't compile that as non-Unicode. `L""` works everywhere, but it won't help you with UTF-8 strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiplatform issues comes from the fact that there are many encodings, and a wrong encoding pick will lead to encÃ³ding Ã­ssues. Once you tackle that problem, you should be able to use `std::wstring` on all your program.

The usual workflow is:

```
raw_input_data = read_raw_data()
input_encoding = "???" // What is your file or terminal encoding?

unicode_data = convert_to_unicode(raw_input_data, input_encoding)

// Do something with the unicode_data, store in some var, etc.

output_encoding = "???" // Is your terminal output encoding the same as your input?
raw_output_data = convert_from_unicode(unicode_data, output_encoding)

print_raw_data(raw_data)
```

Most Unicode issues comes from wrongly detecting the values of `input_encoding` and `output_encoding`. On a modern Linux distribution this is usually UTF-8. On Windows YMMV.

Standard C++ don't know about encodings, you should use some library like [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/) to do the conversion.

Comment: Using these `convert` functions seems logical to me; I also decided to use functions to switch between `std::wstring` and `std::string` in places where it makes sense, rather than entirely updating the app with `string_type`... which would have taken quite a while, let alone to address string literals (and prefixing them with an `L`)

Answer (score 5):

How you store a string within your application is entirely up to you -- after all, nobody would know as long as the strings stay within your application. The problem starts when you try to read or write strings from the outside world (console, files, sockets etc.) and this is where the OS matters.

Linux isn't exactly "agnostic" to Unicode -- it does recognize Unicode but the standard library functions assume UTF-8 encoding, so Unicode strings fit into standard `char` arrays. Windows, on the other hand, uses UTF-16 encoding, so you need a `wchar_t` array to represent 16-bit characters.

The `typedef`s you proposed should work fine, but keep in mind that this alone doesn't make your code portable. As an example, if you want to store text in files in a portable manner, you should choose one encoding and stick to it across all platforms -- this could require converting between encodings on certain platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Linux does support Unicode, it simply uses UTF-8. Probably a better way to make your system portable would be to make use of [International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/) and treat all `std::string` objects as containing UTF-8 characters, and convert them to UTF-16 as needed when invoking Windows functions. It almost always makes sense to use UTF-8 over UTF-16, as UTF-8 uses less space for some of the most commonly used characters (e.g. English*) and more space for less frequent characters, whereas UTF-16 wastes space equally for all characters, no matter how frequently they are used.

While you can use your typedefs, this will mean that you have to write two copies of every single function that has to deal with strings. I think it would be more efficient to simply do all internal computations in UTF-8 and simply translate that to/from UTF-16 if necessary when inputting/outputting  as needed.

*For HTML, XML, and JSON that use English as part of the encoding (e.g. "<html>, <body>, etc.) regardless of the language of the values, this can still be a win for foreign languages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for Linux and using Unicode is that all the IO and most system functions use UTF-8 and the wide character type is 32 bit. Then there is interfacing to Java and other programs which requires UTF-16.

As a suggestion for Unicode support, see the OpenRTL library at http://code.google.com/p/openrtl which supports all UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 on windows, Linux, Osx and Ios. The Unicode support is not just the character types, but also Unicode collation, normalization, case folding, title casing and about 64 different Unicode character properties per full unsigned 32 bit character.

The OpenRTL code is ready now to support char8_t, char16_t and char32_t for the new C++ standards as well, allthough the same character types are supported using macros for existing C and C++ compilers. I think for Unicode and strings processing that it might be what you want for your library.

The point is that if you use OpenRTL, you can build the system using the OpenRTL "char_t" type. This supports the notion that your entire library can be built in either UTF8, UTF16 or UTF32 mode, even on Linux, because OpenRTL is already handling all the interfacing to a lot of system functions like files and io stuff. It has its own print_f functions for example.

By default the char_t is mapping to the wide character type. So on windows it is 32 bit and on Linux it is 32 bit. But you can make it also make it 8 bit everywhere for example. Also it has the support to do fast UTF decoding inside loops using macros.

So instead of ifdeffing between wchar_t and char, you can build everything using char_t and OpenRTL takes care of the rest.